# Reallocating memory to increase size of array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I am fairly new to C, so I am having trouble with realloc().

I have a test case, where I need to lengthen my `kstring`.

I've already used `malloc()` to allocate memory to the array.

Now, I need to lengthen the memory, if `nbytes` is greater than `kstring`.

Here is the code:

```
    void kstrextend(kstring *strp, size_t nbytes)
    {
        kstring *strp1;
        int len=strp->length;
        if(len < nbytes)
        {
            //allocate a new array with larger size
            strp1 = realloc(strp, nbytes);
            //copy older array to new array
            for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
            {
                strp1->data[i]=strp->data[i];
            }
            //remaining space of new array is filled with '\0'
            for (int i = len; i < nbytes; i++)
            {
                strp1->data[i] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm getting core dumps, when I try to reallocate.

Comment: how `kstring` is defined?

Comment: If you are getting `int len=strp->length;` then you surely should be reallocating another field not `strp`: and you won't need to copy the data: `realloc` takes care of that.

Comment: Sure you don't want to reallocate `strp->data` instead of `strp`?

Comment: @immibis I am sure it is the case. Realloc the `data`, update the `length`..

Comment: You must also update `strp->length = bytes`

Comment: Also, `realloc` copies your data to the new array for you.  Your code to "copy older array to new array" is either a no-op (if `realloc` didn't have to move the array), or a segmentation violation waiting to happen (if `realloc` did move the array, in which case the old pointer is invalid). You don't need that code.

Comment: @WeatherVane where would i need to update that at?

Comment: After the (corrected) `realloc` call.

Comment: @WeatherVane okay, so you're saying that i need to realloc something other than strp?

Comment: @ClaytonM9 please see my answer, guessed as you didn't provide full details.

Comment: Is `kstring` your definition or from a library? If from a library, there is almost certainly a whole set of functions already made to operate on `kstring` and you should use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some corrections to your code, untested (no MVCE!)  but I hope it works. Note that there is no need to copy the *old* data because `realloc` ensures the previous memory content is preserved. After `realloc`, the old pointer becomes invalid anyway.

```
void kstrextend(kstring *strp, size_t nbytes)
{
    char *data1;                        // altered type and name
    int len=strp->length;
    if (len < nbytes)
    {
        //allocate a new array with larger size
        data1 = realloc(strp->data, nbytes);
        if (data1 == NULL)
        {
            // take evasive measures
        }
        strp->data = data1;             // replace old pointer
        strp->length = nbytes;          // update length

        //remaining space of new array is filled with '\0'
        for (int i = len; i < nbytes; i++)
        {
            strp->data[i] = '\0';       // use original pointer now
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ClaytonM9 sorry I added one more line mentioned in comments above - update new length.